# How to disable Serialization in play framework?

Tags: java, json, playframework, jackson, sbt

I am using `Play Framework` and `morphia` to deploy the `REST` services. I am getting the following error while passing Generic `Object` as in `Jackson` response

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class java.lang.Object and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: common.ResponseStatusEntity["data"]->entities.Trainer["appointmentNotificaiton"]->entities.notificaitons.AppointmentNotificaiton["data"])
```

How can I disable the Serializer validation in play framework?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `Object` does not have any property and `Jackson` by default does not accept it. To disable it you need to configure `ObjectMapper` like below:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);
```

But mach better is to return some kind of `SUCCESS` object which explicitly tells that everything is `OK`.